# animation in presentation

Tags: animation, slideshow, presentations

I am looking for animation tools to make my presentation, the goal is to create something like this:  [A Youtube video of an animated clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oB44nyPAtlA)

Well, the animation in powerepoint reach its limit when i am trying something like 0:35 - 0:41 in the above clip and 0:25-0:40 in [this clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NmvIWO3GrY&feature=related)

So anybody has experience of making such animation for presentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using a full blown video editor for something like this. Presentation were not designed for such complex animations.